# Как прописать путь к HTML-шаблону находящемуся в другом приложении (django)?

Tags: python, django

После данной ветви цикла **if** я хочу сделать так, чтоб пользователю, после нажатия кнопки, отображало HTML-шаблон, находящейся в другом приложении этого же проекта. Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу прописать путь к данному HTML-шаблону.

```
 if the_user.nick == nick and the_user.password == password:
            current_person = {
               'current_person_id': the_user.id,
               'current_person_nick': the_user.nick,
               'current_person_password': the_user.password,
               'current_person_age': the_user.age
            }
            return render(request, '../USERS/4user/index.html', current_person)
```

Структура проекта следующая:

- **base**

  - setting.py
  - urls.py
  - admin.py
  - ...
- **HOME**

  - setting.py
  - urls.py
  - admin.py
  - views.py (в этом файле и прописан данный код)
  - **templates**

    - index.html
    - ...
- **USERS**

  - setting.py
  - urls.py
  - ...
  - **templates**

    - index.html (а к этому HTML я хочу прописать путь)
    - ...

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, структуру проекта. В общем случае Вам достаточно прописать путь к шаблону от папки `templates` (неважно, что из другого приложения). `Django` ищет шаблоны, используя настройку `TEMPLATES`. [Overriding from an app’s template directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory).

Comment: Вы можете добавить дополнительную информацию в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Обновил вопрос и добавил структуру проекта!

Comment: Не вижу :( Вы сохранили изменения?

Comment: Извините, не сохранил, теперь скорее всего видно.

Answer (score 1):

Один из Ваших шаблонов переопределяет другой, поэтому при текущей структуре проекта Вы не сможете использовать оба.

Вы должны сделать пути до шаблонов уникальными (от директории `templates`). [Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#usage) рекомендует создать подкаталог (например, с именем приложения) в каждой папке `templates`:

> It’s possible – and preferable – to organize templates in
> subdirectories inside each directory containing templates. The
> convention is to make a subdirectory for each Django app, with
> subdirectories within those subdirectories as needed.
>
> Do this for your own sanity. Storing all templates in the root level
> of a single directory gets messy.

***Пример:***

```sh
├───HOME
│   └───templates
│       └───HOME
└───USERS
    └───templates
        └───USERS
```

Тогда Вы сможете обратиться к нужному шаблону так:

```py
'USERS/index.html'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Kama-Pula Рад помочь :) Вы можете отметить этот ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева. Это будет лучшая благодарность.